# Como comparar data com a última data do mês anterior no SQL Firebird?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Estou usando um banco de dados firebird 2,5 tenho um campo data e preciso comparar ele sempre com a última data do mês anterior, exemplo hoje é 21/08/2022, mais preciso trazer todos os registros com o valor 31/07/2022 no campo data, caso seja mês de 30 dias qu fique dinâmico, já fiz no Oracle mais não consegui fazer no firebird.
segue meu sql.
***/* Eventos dos Empregados da Folha */

```
SELECT
   A.EFO_EPG_CODIGO  CODIGO_VENDEDOR,
   E.NOME            NOME_VENDEDOR,
   SUM(A.PARAMETRO)  TOTAL_COMISSAO,
   F.DTCALCULO      DATA_CALCULO
FROM
   EEF A,
   FOL F,
   EPG E
WHERE
    A.EMP_CODIGO = 009
AND F.EMP_CODIGO = A.EMP_CODIGO
AND F.EMP_CODIGO = E.EMP_CODIGO
AND A.EFO_EPG_CODIGO = E.CODIGO
AND A.EVE_CODIGO IN (030, 915)
AND F.ENCERRADA = 'S'
AND A.EFO_FOL_SEQ = F.SEQ
AND F.DTCALCULO = #########AQUI DEVERIA ENTRAR A COMPARAÇÃO COM A ÚLTIMA DATA DO MÊS ANTERIOR
GROUP BY
    A.EFO_EPG_CODIGO,
    F.DTCALCULO,
    E.NOME***
```

Comment: Lead e lag ? https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html

Answer (score 0):

Segue sugestão para calculo do ultimo dia do mes anterior utilizando-se a função Extract para extrair o dia da data atual e a função DateAdd para subtrair o dia atual da data atual:

```
AND F.DTCALCULO = dateadd(day, extract(day from current_date) * -1, current_date)
```